# Can't remove generated product data on single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to hide product data on single product page, I tried many solutions like using the hooks of 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' but without any result

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'structured_data_product_nulled', 10, 2 );

    function structured_data_product_nulled( $markup, $product ){
        $markup = '' ;
        return $markup;
    }
```

but I can't remove the generated data, this is the function

[Here are the attributes that i wan't to hide, they're allready in tabs i don't want them to be shown in the description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEZea.png)

Comment: Is that attributes?

Comment: yes it is, variable attributes that i added and i don't want them to be shown in the description

Comment: https://datafeedrapi.helpscoutdocs.com/article/206-hide-specific-attributes-from-the-additional-information-tab

Answer (score 0):

I would hide usng CSS as its the fastest way.
Just open google chrome right-click the items and select inspector.

Get in the Inspector click the + in the top right hand corner this will create a new CSS class for the element.

type

```
 display:none
```

and if the element dissapears copy and paste the CSS into th wordpress admin Apperance > Customiser Additional CSS.

This will hide those items.